# Dont understand the message

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm currently following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jazNUpO3lQ&list=PLeo1K3hjS3uvCeTYTeyfe0-rN5r8zn9rw&index=2

That's the code from tutorial

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['area']],df.price)

--LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None,
         normalize=False)
```

After writing this specific code, That's my code

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

reg.fit(df[['Area']],df.Price)

   --LinearRegression()   # Its not showing same as the tutorial code

reg.predict([[3300]])  # after running this code its showing the below message and also giving the output  

D:\New folder\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:450: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names
  warnings.warn(

  array([628715.75342466])
```

Why is my code not showing same out as tutorial

```
--LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False)
```

And what is the meaning of this message

```
D:\New folder\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:450: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names
  warnings.warn(
```